# How to change the value of props when user click right or left arrow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have created a task management application using reactjs. User can add task in each steps. When user clicks on left button or right button the task should change the step. I have tried but the problem I didn't get how to change the value of props when right or left button are clicked. Here is what i have tried.There are 4 steps.

**App.js**

```
import StatusLine from "./components/StatusLine/StatusLine";
import './App.css'

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Task Management</h1>
      <main>
        <section>
          <StatusLine
            status='Step 1'  />

          <StatusLine
            status='Step 2'  />

          <StatusLine
            status='Step 3'  />

          <StatusLine
            status='Step 4'  />
        </section>
      </main>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**StatusLine.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Task from "../Task/Task";
import "./StatusLine.css";
import axios from '../../config/axios'

const StatusLine = (props) => {
  const { status } = props;
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  let taskList, taskForStatus;
  let stepStatus = status;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTask() {
      const res = await axios.get("/get-task", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      setTasks(res.data);
    }
    getTask();
  }, []);

 async function moveTask(id, newStatus) {
    stepStatus = newStatus;
    let task = tasks?.filter((task) => task.id === id);
    let filteredTask = tasks?.filter((task) => task.id !== id);
    task[0].status = newStatus;
    let changedStatus=filteredTask.concat(task)
    setTasks(changedStatus);
    await axios.post('/move-task',{id,stepStatus},{withCredentials:true})
  } 

  if (tasks) {
    taskForStatus = tasks?.filter((task) => task.status === stepStatus);
  }

  if (taskForStatus) {
    taskList = taskForStatus.map((task) => {
      return (
        <Task
          deleteTask={(id) => deleteTask(id)}
          moveTask={(id, status) => moveTask(id, status)}
          key={task.id}
          task={task}
        />
      );
    });
  }
  return (
    
    <div className="statusLine">
      <h3>{stepStatus}</h3>
      {taskList}
      <button onClick={handleAddEmpty} className="button addTask">
        +
      </button>
      <AddTask
        modalOpen={modalOpen}
        setModalOpen={setModalOpen}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default StatusLine;
```

**Task.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BsFillArrowLeftCircleFill,
  BsFillArrowRightCircleFill,
  BsFillTrashFill,
} from "react-icons/bs";
import "./Task.css";

const Task = (props) => {
  const { deleteTask, moveTask, task } = props;

  function handleMoveLeft() {
    let newStatus = "";

    if (task.status === "Step 2") {
      newStatus = "Step 1";
    } else if (task.status === "Step 3") {
      newStatus = "Step 2";
    } else if (task.status === "Step 4") {
      newStatus = "Step 3";
    }

    if (newStatus !== "") {
      moveTask(task.id, newStatus);
    }
  }

  function handleMoveRight() {
    let newStatus = "";

    if (task.status === "Step 1") {
      newStatus = "Step 2";
    } else if (task.status === "Step 2") {
      newStatus = "Step 3";
    } else if (task.status === "Step 3") {
      newStatus = "Step 4";
    }

    if (newStatus !== "") {
      moveTask(task.id, newStatus);
    }
  }

  function handleDelete() {
    deleteTask(task.id);
  }

  return (
    <div className="TaskMain">
      <div className="task">
        <button onClick={handleMoveLeft} className="button moveTask">
          <BsFillArrowLeftCircleFill />
        </button>
        <p className="title">{task.title}</p>

        <button onClick={handleMoveRight} className="button moveTask">
          <BsFillArrowRightCircleFill />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="taskDelete">
        <button className="button delete" onClick={handleDelete}>
          <BsFillTrashFill />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the value of props of Task Component in Task Component.
you need change task props on parent of Task. you can define handleMoveRight and handleMoveLeft handler on StatusLine and pass them to Task and use on left and right button.

also you can use [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have doubt regarding the props that is passing from app.js. It is determining the step. can you suggest me any better method?

Comment: use context or redux.